# CPU starts running at 100% when charging

Tags: 20.04, cpu, process

My CPUs start alternating at 100% at seemingly random intervals, even though no process is using excessive amounts of CPU.
I have noticed that this behaviour seems to occur when I am charging my notebook from low-ish battery levels.

Comment: Can you copy/paste a view of `top` when the processor is using 100% ?

Comment: I was just in the process of coyping, when the behaviour stopped. There was nothing out of the ordinary, though. My browser used the most at around 5%, then came gnome-shell and web content ect. at around 2%. All in all, that shouldn't explain the erratic behaviour, should it?

Comment: If you say you have 100% cpu usage, you will have one or more processes in `top` using the cpu(s). `top` shows pr default the processes with highest cpu usage.

Comment: That's the thing, though. There wasn't any process using the cpu. And the CPU cores were erratically alternating between 0-5% usage and 100% usage.

Comment: Facing the same issue.. any resolution?

Comment: Hi! Not really any solution... I noticed that this behaviour seems to be connected to a specific application running. So when I plug in my laptop, and the CPU starts working excessively, I will restart the application in question which will resolve the issue.